# Filter table columns and route to different table if it is null

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I don't know much about SQL but still I would like to ask this forum.

My job is to handle records with null values. I mean we have natural keys (suppose 4 columns) where in if any of the column gets `NULL` values into it, then that should be routed to another table so that it can be reported to client.

AFAIK `SQL` gives only one output and cannot be split. Is there any way we can handle this in `SQL`/`spark SQL`? I need to execute this job using `spark`.

Process flow is :

1. first data is sqooped and kept in hive table
2. I need to take this data and check for null values.
3. store it in next level tables

Comment: _"SQL gives only one output"_ > true, but you could also create a single table with 2 partitions, e.g. `status=GOOD` vs `status=BAD` and compute `status` pseudocolumn in an INSERT SELECT with dynamic partitioning... All records would be exposed by default, but then you could filter out based on `status`.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can't do it in one go, you can do it by the steps mentioned.

After the table is created in Hive, using PySpark you could do,

```
#Set all the imports and enable Hive support for the session
#Dataframe to hold rows where either of 4 columns is null
df=spark.sql("select * from tblName where col1 is null or col2 is null or col3 is null or col4 is null")
#Write the resulting dataframe to a Hive table
df.saveAsTable('tableName') #Use other arguments in saveAsTable as required
```

Comment: Thanks, but i need to have two tables, one with records with all not null values in the specified columns and another with records atleast having on null value in the columns specified. in the above suggestion, tblName will hold all the records and tableName will hold null value records .....
can we do this way in hive

first load 100 records in tab1 and then run a check on it for null, if a record is found insert it into tab2 and delete it from tab1 .. is this the suggested approach if the records are in millions ?